# Do I NEED a subquery on this OVER example?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So, I've got this query where I need the average of "value". I need that join because the table has versions based on the bulk load time - so the same year/month can have multiple versions, but I want only the latest.

```
select *, 
    avg(value) over (
        order by YEAR, MONTH
        ROWS 11 preceding) as averageValue
 from
(
    SELECT
        c.YEAR,
        c.MONTH,
        PRODUCT,
        value
    FROM
        db.table c
    join (
        select year, month, max(version) as version
        from db.table
        group by year, month
        ) v
    on c.year = v.year
    and c.month = v.month
    and c.version = v.version
) a
order by year desc, month desc
```

Do I really need to put my main query as a subquery, to get avg()over() of the field? If I try to do it straight on the main query, all I'm getting is the full value instead of the desired average of the last twelve months...

Comment: post the failing query too.

Comment: hm... I think what I'm having trouble with is the order inside the OVER clause... I just retried almost the same query, but duplicating the average inside the main query using order with DESC and it seems to work now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here was I wasn't using DESC as I should on the OVER clause - so even if the query had ordering year/month DESC, the OVER clause didn't.

Now, this query, works as it should:

```
SELECT
        c.YEAR,
        c.MONTH,
        PRODUCT,
        value,
        avg(value) over (
            order by YEAR desc, MONTH desc
            ROWS 11 preceding
        ) as averageValue
    FROM
        db.table c
    join (
        select year, month, max(version) as version
        from db.table
        group by year, month
        ) v
    on c.year = v.year
    and c.month = v.month
    and c.version = v.version
    order by year desc, month desc
```